# Am looking for a manga where the mc has a miniature world or like a space where he can control like a god

Tags: story-identification, manga

Am looking for a manga where the mc has a miniature world or like a space where he can control like a god and this is an advantage for him.

Comment: I'm afraid we need more details. Black and white? Color? DId you read it on paper or online? Is this a "system", "cultivation", or "isekai" story? How was being able to control this small world an advantage for him?

Comment: Thank you for responding it was a color ,if i remember correctly there was a system but i don't remember how he controlled the world because I stopped around there when he got it but in the creation of the world it depended on his thinking or something like that but he created similar to how the bible played out creation  and I don't remember y it was an advantage but it was

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to check out *Swallowed Star*?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *Swallowed Star* with Luo Feng and his "[I Am the Universe](https://swallowed-star.fandom.com/wiki/I_am_the_Universe)" power?

> This technique was extremely powerful. When it was performed, godly power was burned and transformed into a micro-universe, allowing the user to trap his enemies inside the universe. Inside the micro-universe, the enemies’ power was significantly weakened, whereas Luo Feng’s own power surged within it. If he chose to self-destruct, the enemies would be annihilated instantly!

[image: Luo Feng]

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any readily available panels for him using the ability.

Answer (score 0):

***[Eternal Club](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/s5fn8yq/eternal-club)***.

Mr. Lu made a miniature world so he can obtain more lifespan. A must read series.

> Chen Li works at Mo city, he works there every day with no hope to be seen for the future… until one night. Chen Li obtains a special ability, an ability to buy “Time” and “Lifespan” from people, sell “Time” and “Lifespan” and also let things speed up “Time leap” and slow down “exhaustion time”. So he begins to build a top-class “Lifespan club”!